# WTforms QuerySelectField , SelectField , MultipleSelectField doesn't seem to work with validate_on_submit()

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

So I have a form with QuerySelect field and String fields . When i try to submit it and validate it on the server side it just doesn't happen . The POST request is going through with the correct data , but it never enters the if form.validate_on_submit() . I am going crazy over this , help would be greatly appreciated.

Also the forms validate if I remove the SelectFields.In the below example i'm using the MultipleSeletField

Here's the code :

here's my route logic :

app.py

```
 @app.route('/contacts' , methods=['GET' , 'POST'])
 @login_required
 def contacts():
        '''
            Add contacts to database with option to export 
            and import data onto Peep.
        '''
        user = current_user.username 
        form = login_model.AddContactForm()
        form_add_group = login_model.AddGroupForm()
        form_add_group.contact.choices = [ (r.id , r.company_name ) for r in login_model.AddContact.query.order_by('company_name') ]

        if form_add_group.validate_on_submit():
            print("going in")
            return "{}{}".format(form_add_group.group.data , form_add_group.contact.data)

        mssg = ""
        contact_list = db.session.query(login_model.AddContact).all() 




        return render_template('contacts.html' , user = user ,form = form , error_mssg_a ="Testing the error run" ,
        contact_list = contact_list , form_add_group=form_add_group) , 200
```

model.py:

```
class AddGroupForm(FlaskForm):
    group = QuerySelectField('group' , allow_blank = False , get_label = 'group' , query_factory = group_choice)
    contact= SelectMultipleField('contact' )
```

Here's the template :

```
<form action="/contacts" method="POST">
            {{form_add_group.hidden_tag()}}

            <div class="select control">
            {{form_add_group.group}}
            </div>

            <div class="select control is-multiple" width="8">
                {{form_add_group.contact}}
            </div>


            <button class="button is-black"><i class="icon-btn" data-feather="check-square"></i>Create Group</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you get any validation errors on the form?

Comment: Yes I got this : 
` '2' is not a valid choice for this field `

Comment: I think it's the coerce parameter that I'm not setting . But what about the QuerySelectField it doesn't take coerce argument

Comment: Are you using multi select field widget to create your own SelectMultipleField?

Comment: Only QuerySelectField doesn't work because it doesn't have a **coerce** parameter , the SelectFields seems to work just fine.